# Android Intent filter for opening App from browser

Tags: android, android-activity, browser, intentfilter

I have a website and now i'm creating a android app for it. But i try to open the app if you are on the browser and you want to open my website it automaticly redirects to my android app. But the big question is how can I redirect to a different activity if the url is different?

for now I have this.

```
<activity
    android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="mywebsite.com"/>
        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.mywebsite.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

HomeActivity must be opened if you go to the home webpage example: `www.mywebsite.com` or `www.mywebsite.com/`

```
<activity android:name=".SpecificActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="mywebsite.com"
            android:pathPattern="/.*"/>
        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="www.mywebsite.com"
            android:pathPattern="/.*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The SpecificActivity must be opened if you enter the website with a extra path
example: `www.mywebsite.com/cats` or `www.mywebsite.com/123456` or `www.mywebsite.com/iamnumber1`

for now if i enter the website in google the dialog opens but I can choose between the HomeActivity or SpecificActivity how can I fix this that if there is nothing behind the url except for a `/` the HomeActivity opens otherwise the SpecificActivity opens.

[image: The blue is to open SpecificActivity]

**SOLUTION**

https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/19a9ab51d0567ecfd378622d68f1cd1f

Thanks to Selvin

Comment: Same result as /.*

Comment: And how's about /..* ? It seems like it's a pattern to match 1 or more occurance of characters.

Comment: nuuneoi comment + `android:pathPattern="/"` in `HomeActivity` filters

Comment: this fixed the HomeActivity so mywebsite.com/ and mywesbite.com is now opening in HomeActivity, but when I enter mywebsite.com/Cats it opens the dialog and let me choose between the two activities

Comment: @Selvin that fixed the SpecificActivity but then the HomeActivity will let me choose

Comment: @Selvin and the mywebsite.com doesn't work at all now

Comment: I found It, i needed to add /..+ in the pathPattern of my SpecificActivity and no pathPattern in the HomeActivity, thanks everybody!

Comment: it is not working for me (on Sony Experia z3 compat) `am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://mywebsite.com` with your manifest is showing only `HomeActivity` ... `am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://mywebsite.com/aaaa` too ... I would rather try a ProxyActivity (invisible without setContent call) which would be take all "calls" for http://mywebsite.com and choose the right "real" activity based on intent data

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/19a9ab51d0567ecfd378622d68f1cd1f

Comment: Yes this is indeed a much better solution